# How do I disable root login?

Tags: login, root

I wanted to try the root login ( GUI mode ) but I am a bit scared that I might mess up something so I want to disable it. How do I do it?

Comment: I believe it is disabled by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes but I enabled it. I got scared. :P

Answer (score 3):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Re-disabling_your_root_account

> If for some reason you have enabled your root account and wish to
>   disable it again, use the following command in terminal...

```
sudo passwd -dl root
```

It was the first result when I googled "ubuntu root login". Google is your friend :)

Comment: Did not work. I used this command to enable it. [ sudo sh -c 'echo "greeter-show-manual-login=true" >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf' ]

Comment: never mind. Figured it myself